# Is there a way to @JsonIgnore by default, and a tag to allow serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my case, adding @JsonIgnore everytime i add a new methode in java model is not very convenient.

I would prefere by default ignore everything, and add a marker when a serialization is needed.

Is there a simple way to implement that ?

Comment: Unless you have millions of methods, surely adding 11 more characters to the method declaration (or copying and pasting it) should not be a problem. To answer your question, I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use a "customized" ObjectMapper like this one:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getDeserializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
        .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

this will Ignore everything that is not marked with `@JsonProperty`